# Difference between directory entry and a link in linux?

Tags: filesystems

What is the difference between a link and a directory entry. Is every link (symbolic and hard link) a directory entry? What is a directory entry, which is not a link for example?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, on POSIX-alike file systems, everything that has a filesystem "address" (a *path*) is a directory entry. Files, other directories, symlinks, character device files.

A hard link is just a normal file which happens to appear under two different paths.

Answer (score 0):

On a traditional linux filesystem, every file is a inode.  For real files typically the inode points to datablocks.

A directory entry that points to an inode.  Multiple such directory entries can point to the same inode, and they can not be distinguished.  When there is more than one, they are called hard links.  The inode has a reference counter indicating how many hard links the inode has (and is displayed by `ls -l`).

A symbolic link is a special inode that instead of pointing to data blocks,   contains another filename, so rather than linking to an inode, it links to another directory entry by name (which may or may not exist).

Answer (score 0):

A file link and a directory entry are the same thing. It's a matter of perspective: a link to a file is an entry in a directory. It's called a directory entry when viewed from the directory's perspective, and a link when viewed from the file's perspective.

Note that here, “link” is a *hard* link. Symbolic links are a different concept.

This equivalence only apply to filesystems that do have a concept of “link”, i.e. where there is a level of indirection between directory entries and files. More particularly, this applies to filesystems where a file can have multiple links, i.e. on filesystems that support hard links. On filesystems where a file is in a given directory and that's it, the concept of “link” doesn't apply (whereas the concept of directory entry applies on any filesystem that has directories).

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem
I have /usr/local/bin->/LinuxStuff/bin
This link is created with:
rmdir /usr/local/bin followed up by
ln -s /usr/local/bin /LinuxStuff/bin

But I have a utility that does create an entry to /etc/fstab as the following.
/LinuxStuff/bin /usr/local/bin none bind,defaults 0 0

When the program encounters that fstab entry, or Linux kernel encounters the ln -s link ==>>> the result is Crash Segment fault.

How can I distinguish between a ... /bin and a ... /bin that has a link or has already had the  ln -s or bind applied